# Working with views, better use various displays or create more views?

Tags: views, 8

The main task is:

**Create a couple of pages with terms of a specific list of taxonomy vocabulary. (Its about 20+ pages).**

So, its simple, create a view with a particular route, and set to display taxonomy terms, set the right vocabulary to display, set exposed filters and so on.

Now comes the question, speaking in perfomance, its better create a view to each page (with almost the same config, only vocabulary terms is different), or create just one view and create a display for each page?

Both scenarios work's great, using just one view for all pages and using a view for each page, but which one can be the best alternative for this case?

Looking in [Working with Views in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/1912118), there is nothing about perfomance and best practice. Any advice are welcome.

Comment: Since your views get cached, performance wise, no diff.

Comment: My concern is not performance (which would be the same) but maintaining these 20+ views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book "Mastering Drupal 8 Views" Greg Marshall suggests that there is no strong reason to prefer one or the other. He suggests using separate views most of the time, for the simple reason that it's very easy to make a mistake in the UI and apply a change to all displays when that wasn't what you wanted.

I would suggest that you think carefully about in what circumstances you are going to want to modify a view. If changes are likely to affect all displays, or be only applicable to one display of a certain type, then having a single view is fine.

If changes would likely be to multiple characteristics that could apply to all displays but you would want to be different on each display, then isolating them as separate views reduces the risk of getting in a mess.